# How can I config vuetify with nuxtjs to deploy on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, vuetify.js, fatal-error, nuxtjs

I'm trying to run on app engine with nuxtjs and vuetify but I'm getting this error:
Error: Cannot find module 'vuetify/es5/util/colors'

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "nuxt": "2.14.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.11.2",
}
```

nuxt.config.js

```
import colors from 'vuetify/es5/util/colors'

export default {
    buildModules: [
        '@nuxtjs/vuetify',
    ],

    vuetify: {
        theme: {
            dark: true,
            themes: {
                dark: {
                    primary: colors.blue.darken2,
                    accent: colors.grey.darken3,
                    secondary: colors.amber.darken3,
                    info: colors.teal.lighten1,
                    warning: colors.amber.base,
                    error: colors.deepOrange.accent4,
                    success: colors.green.accent3,
                },
            },
        },
    },
}
```

Error:
[Error: Cannot find module 'vuetify/es5/util/colors'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsqFZ.png)

Answer (score 2):

Solution I've found is move nuxtjs/vuetify from devDependencies to dependencies

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Yes, move from devDependencies to dependencies like this.
I hope, it'll work for you.